# How to split telephone input into different boxes (one number per box) using css

Tags: css, user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience

I want to split the each number input into individual boxes. I want it for visual look.

For eg. when we fill out forms each letter is in a box ( 1 letter per box ).
Is there a way to do this in CSS.

Please refer to the image below and look at the input for PAN, Date of formation.

I want to implement the same thing using css so that when the user inputs, each letter appears in the respective block.

[image: two muppets]

Comment: When the number is submitted, do you want it submitted as individual digits, or as a single longer numeric string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the lines using a background gradient and layer them over the input. You'll need to use a monospace font to keep everything aligned. And you'll also need to set a `maxlength` on the input.

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.lines {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  /* create lines */
  background-image: linear-gradient(
  to right, 
  black 1px, 
  transparent 1px);
  background-size: 2ch;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  font: inherit;
  
  padding: .25ch .5ch;
  letter-spacing: 1ch;
  max-width: 20ch;
}


/* for demo, ignore */
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="tel" maxlength="9">
  <span class="lines"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @KarReddy Oh the `maxlength` value is 9, try update that to 10